# Cannot resolve FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm getting the error

```
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
```

even though i'm setting my pending intent correctly

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            }
```

what am i doing wrong?
does anyone know a way to fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried to replace ```PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE``` with ```PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE``` ?

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani yes of coures it didn't help it's the same issue

Comment: Are you sure that this is the `PendingIntent` that is causing the problem? A lot of people get bitten by `PendingIntent` objects created by libraries.

Answer (score 0):

just do that

```
val flag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
} else {
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
}


val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, flag)
```